# VS2010 Beta 2 > Setup Project > Prerequisites > Missing .NET 3.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, in a Setup project, in Prerequisites, there's no option to include the .NET Framework 3.0 prerequisite. How do I change things so that it is an available option?

[image]

My goal is to create an .msi installer that is launched by a Setup.exe. The Setup.exe should install .NET 3.0 if it's not there. The application that I'm installing uses .NET 3.0

Note: I've tried clicking the "Check Microsoft Update for more redistributable components", but .NET 3.0 wasn't there.

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 1):

If your app was buil against 3.0 but doesn't use wpf wcf or workflow foundation, you can run on 3.5 just fine

Comment: My end users may be less likely to have .NET 3.5 SP1 than .NET 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Copy Folder DotNetFX35SP1  (Include file)

Address : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

Comment: Please explain your answer.